# Shader Nodes: how to use instancer's vertex attribute to get different colors for instances

Tags: shader-nodes, instances

I want to apply a color defined in the instancer's vertex attribute *my_color* to get the same color for the related instance. It does not work in the simple setup that I will describe below.

I created a Blender object *Verts* that consists of 4 vertices. The object *Verts* will be used as an instancer.

[image: Blender object Verts]

I created an attribute *my_color* (domain:Vertex, data type: Color) for the object *Verts* and set some values for it:

[image: Attribute my_color]

I parented the object *Cube* (the instance) to the object *Verts* and set the instance type to *Vertices*

[image: Instancing]

I created the following material for the object *Cube* (the instance):

[image: Material]

The colors from the attribute *my_color* of the object *Verts* (the instancer) aren't applied to the object *Cube* (the instance).

[image: Result]

How to solve this task?

[image]

Comment: This feature isn't supported yet according to https://developer.blender.org/T98437